# WHat is an ebay style auction?

Tags: extensions

I am looking for the best auction extension for Magento that allows only myself to sell on my website but with the same feel as an ebay auction for the buyers when bidding.

Please let me know 
I see the ones you can google but I dont think these are very attractive looking nor do they look smooth feeling 
HELP!

Answer (score 1):

The extensions of Aheadworks work quite well in general, you could give this module a try:
http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/auction-pro.html

If you don't like the looks, you can rework them after you've installed one of the available auction extensions found anywhere.

If you don't like the way they work, I think you should consider writing your own module for this.